# How can I paste to a range with VBA if the range is defined by variables changing with a "for i" loop?

Tags: excel, vba

so what I'm trying to do is run through a long list of values and check if the value in column A is equal to the list in column F and then if thats true, check if the month in column B is equal to the horizontal list of months in row 1 columns f:ab and then if both conditions are met, paste the value in the correct grid square...otherwise continue looping through i values and once it gets to the end of i values, then loop to the next j and begin again.  It keeps getting stuck on my paste function but I can't understand why.

Heres the code:

```
Dim i As Integer
For j = 6 To 28
    For i = 2 To 4061
    If Range("A" & i).Value = Range("F" & i).Value Then
        If Range("B" & i).Value = Cells(1, j + 5).Value Then
            Range("D" & i).Copy
            Range(Cells(i, j)).Paste
        End If
    End If
    Next i
Next j
```

Comment: A `Range` does not have a `Paste` method. Plus you shouldn't wrap `Cells` in `Range`. `Range("D" & i).Copy Destination:=Cells(i, j)`

Comment: to me the loops seem inverted.  If you put the j loop inside the first If in the i loop it would not loop for that row if the first if is false, saving some looping.